# php ajax form submit without refresh parent page

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, events, submit

i have some issues for ajax form submit

```
$("#send").on("click", function() {

$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ads_process.php",
            data: $("#ads").serialize(),
            success: function(){
                if(data == "true") {
                    $("#ads").fadeOut("fast", function(){
                        //$(this).before("<p><strong>Success! Your message has been sent, thanks!</strong></p>");
                        setTimeout("$.ads.close()", 2000);
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
        });
```

a page have list of data there is button for comment, when it click a popup window open. i write comment and submit but the problem is that a parent page is refresh i dont want refresh a parent page only i want submit the data, insert in database and popup window will be closed
and data will be shown on parent page.

can any body help me

=====================================================================================

Nothing Happen I Post my Complete Code::

HTML FILE ::

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../js/jQuery_1-9-0.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

<a href="" class="topopup">popup</a>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $("#send").on("click", function() {

        events.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ads_process.php",
        data: $("#ads").serialize(),
        success: function(data){
            if(data == "true") {
                $("#ads").fadeOut("fast", function(){
                    //$(this).before("<p><strong>Success! Your message has been sent, thanks!</strong></p>");
                    setTimeout("$.ads.close()", 2000);
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<div id="toPopup"> 

    <div class="close"></div>
    <span class="ecs_tooltip">Press Esc to close <span class="arrow"></span></span>
    <div id="popup_content"> <!--your content start-->
    <form action="" method="post" id="ads">

    <div class="formMainDiv">

        <div class="formDiv">

            <div class="lableHeading">
                Agent Name:
            </div>
            <div class="inputDiv">
                <input type="text" name="txtAgentName" id="txtAgentName" class="inputFeild" />
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="formDiv">

            <div class="lableHeading">
                Ad ID:
            </div>
            <div class="inputDiv">
                <input type="text" name="txtAdsId" id="txtAdsId" class="inputFeild" />
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="formDiv">

            <div class="lableHeading">
                Comments:
            </div>
            <div class="inputDiv">
                <textarea name="txtComments" id="txtComments" class="inputText"></textarea>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="formDiv">

            <div class="lableHeading">
                Call Reason:
            </div>
            <div class="inputDiv">
                <input type="radio" name="rdReason" id="rdReason" value="Not Responding at the moment" />
                <label class="lableText">
                    Not Responding at the moment&nbsp;&nbsp;
                </label>
                <input type="radio" name="rdReason" id="rdReason" value="Busy" />
                <label class="lableText">
                    Busy&nbsp;&nbsp;
                </label>
                <input type="radio" name="rdReason" id="rdReason" value="Call back" />
                <label class="lableText">
                    Call back&nbsp;&nbsp;
                </label>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="formDiv">

            <div class="lableHeading">
                Other Resaons:
            </div>
            <div class="inputDiv">
                <textarea name="txtOtherReason" id="txtOtherReason" class="inputText"></textarea>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="formDiv">

            <div class="lableHeading">
                Call Status:
            </div>
            <div class="inputDiv">
                <img src="/images/icon/green.png" />
                    <input name="rdFoneStatus" type="radio" value="1">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <img src="/images/icon/red.png" />
                    <input name="rdFoneStatus" type="radio" value="2">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <img src="/images/icon/gray.png" />
                    <input name="rdFoneStatus" type="radio" value="3">
            </div>

        </div>

        <div style="float:right; margin:18px 0 0">
            <button id="send" class="button">Submit</button>
        </div>

    </div>

    </form>
    </div> <!--your content end-->

</div> <!--toPopup end-->

<div class="loader"></div>
<div id="backgroundPopup"></div>
```

JS File::

```
/* 
    author: istockphp.com
*/
jQuery(function($) {

    $("a.topopup").click(function() {
            loading(); // loading
            setTimeout(function(){ // then show popup, deley in .5 second
                loadPopup(); // function show popup 
            }, 500); // .5 second
    return false;
    });

    /* event for close the popup */
    $("div.close").hover(
                    function() {
                        $('span.ecs_tooltip').show();
                    },
                    function () {
                        $('span.ecs_tooltip').hide();
                    }
                );

    $("div.close").click(function() {
        disablePopup();  // function close pop up
    });

    $(this).keyup(function(event) {
        if (event.which == 27) { // 27 is 'Ecs' in the keyboard
            disablePopup();  // function close pop up
        }   
    });

    $("div#backgroundPopup").click(function() {
        disablePopup();  // function close pop up
    });

    $('a.livebox').click(function() {
        alert('Hello World!');
    return false;
    });


     /************** start: functions. **************/
    function loading() {
        $("div.loader").show();  
    }
    function closeloading() {
        $("div.loader").fadeOut('normal');  
    }

    var popupStatus = 0; // set value

    function loadPopup() { 
        if(popupStatus == 0) { // if value is 0, show popup
            closeloading(); // fadeout loading
            $("#toPopup").fadeIn(0500); // fadein popup div
            $("#backgroundPopup").css("opacity", "0.7"); // css opacity, supports IE7, IE8
            $("#backgroundPopup").fadeIn(0001); 
            popupStatus = 1; // and set value to 1
        }   
    }

    function disablePopup() {
        if(popupStatus == 1) { // if value is 1, close popup
            $("#toPopup").fadeOut("normal");  
            $("#backgroundPopup").fadeOut("normal");  
            popupStatus = 0;  // and set value to 0
        }
    }
    /************** end: functions. **************/
}); // jQuery End
```

Comment: You need to clarify if the popup is a separate window or something like a floating div (ie it's actually part of the "parent"). As submitting a form will change the page so preventdefault() will work http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Comment: The DOM isn't loaded when your code runs. Check my answer there are a couple of issues that need dealing with

Comment: It would be greatly appreciated if you were to accept and/or upvote helpful answers. If you don't know how to do this, [check this page](http://stackoverflow.com/about) to find out why this is done, and how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
$("#send").on("click", function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ads_process.php",
            //Specify the datatype of response if necessary
            data: $("#ads").serialize(),
            success: function(data){
                if(data == "true") {
                    $("#ads").fadeOut("fast", function(){
                        //$(this).before("<p><strong>Success! Your message has been sent, thanks!</strong></p>");
                        setTimeout("$.ads.close()", 2000);
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

By using prevent default you can stop the form refreshing the page like so:
http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

```
$("#send").on("click", function(events) {
    events.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ads_process.php",
                data: $("#ads").serialize(),
                success: function(){
                    if(data == "true") {
                        $("#ads").fadeOut("fast", function(){
                            //$(this).before("<p><strong>Success! Your message has been sent, thanks!</strong></p>");
                            setTimeout("$.ads.close()", 2000);
                            });
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

First let me say this:
You're binding an event listener, but the DOM is probably not ready, yet: wrap your code in a `$(document).ready(function(){});` callback
Then: `setTimeout("$.ads.close()", 2000);` is bad practice. `setTimeout` should be passed a reference to a function object, not a string, replace it with:

```
setTimeout(function()
{
    $.ads.close();
}, 2000);
```

Next
You, indeed, neet to `preventDefault` the event, to prevent its default behaviour to get executed. Though this doesn't prevent the event from propagating/bubbling through the dom. If the clicked element is a submit button, the form might still get submitted (and the page will be refreshed). 
To stop this from happening, either call both `preventDefault()` and `stopPropagation()`, or (since you're using jQuery), you can simply return `false`, which does the same thing as calling both methods.

In your case, though, I'd attach the event handler to the form, and listen for the `submit` event:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#form').on('submit', function(e)
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'your/url',
            data: $(this),
            success: function(data)
            {//do stuff
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
        return false;
        //or
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();//strictly speaking, not required here
    });
});
```

That should disable the form being submitted when the client uses a keystroke (like enter) to submit the form, too.

Foot-note: the `language` attribute of the script tag has been deprecated since 1999, just `type` will do