# Load the target page on the same page after submitting a form

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

To begin with, there's an `include` function in PHP:

> The `include (or require)` statement takes all the text/code/markup that exists in the specified file and copies it into the file that uses the include statement.
> https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_includes.asp

I have an HTML form with an action link and once I submit the form, it redirects me to that target page.

What I'd like to do is instead of redirecting me to that target page, the contents of the target page will load on the same page as the form like how `include` works. It won't be a new page, it will still be the same but the contents of the target page will be added into it. How would I go about this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [php ajax form submit without refresh parent page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17610388/php-ajax-form-submit-without-refresh-parent-page)

Comment: You should really be providing reproducible examples of what you have tried to achieve so far. You should also be doing a significant amount of research first to find what you're looking for. A google search would have brought plenty up for this.